# Environment Variables across different CNames hosted on Azure?

Tags: asp.net, azure

The project I’m planning requires a site per client, after some research it seems that the best way to achieve this is with CNames. So if I have www.site.com, I can [programmatically add a new site like client1.site.com](http://www.dotnetexpertguide.com/2012/04/aspnet-iis-dns-records-sub-domain-on.html).

The question I have is how would I have environment variables for each CName in an ASP.NET application that will be hosted on Azure?

So each client will have their own settings, site descriptions, colours, other custom options. If not environment variables, how can these be accessed?

If using CNames isn’t the best approach to this problem, what would be the best alternative?

**EDIT**

Only one copy of the application will be running that will be accessed through multiple CNAMEs

Comment: Is there only one copy of the ASP.NET application running that will be accessed through multiple CNAME?

Comment: Yes @Claies that's correct, I don't want to do n amount of deployments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have here is that you apply environment variables to an individual application. If you want a set of environment variables per CNAME, then you need an application per CNAME.

A better solution would be to specify a wildcard domain for the Web App, and have all traffic directed to a single application. Then let the application check the incoming request for the CNAME and apply whatever parameters are required at that point.

Comment: That makes sense, so how do sites like tumblr, or Visual Studio Online do it?

Comment: If you [look](http://www.digwebinterface.com/?hostnames=*.tumblr.com&type=A&ns=resolver&useresolver=8.8.4.4&nameservers=) at tumblr's DNS record there is a wildcard entry that points everything to their frontend IP address. Decisions would then be made in code about what was shown. I imagine VSO is the same.

Comment: Thank you very much Michael. That makes a lot of sense, I'll look deeper into this tonight.